# How can I configure a continuous layout simulation in Cytoscape force-directed graphs?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'm using Cytoscape-JS to visualize a (rather small) graph via a force-directed layout. The layout algorithm itself is not too important. Currently, I just do something like this (I'm using Typescript by the way):

```
this.cyLayout = this.cytoscape.elements().createLayout({
  name: 'cola'
});
this.cyLayout.run();
```

Is there any way to have a continuous layout, meaning whenever I drag a node, the layout should be updated continuously and the network should stabilize again according to the rules of the force-directed algorithm. I've googled quite a bit but I can't seem to find a solution. In my opinion, this is quite standard behavior (other libraries offer this by default) and should be configurable through a simple option.

I'd be really grateful for a solution, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use cola.js, there actually is a layout property just for that.

You can take a look at the cola.js [GitHub page](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-cola), where you will find the `infinite: true` option. This continues the layout calculation infinitely and does just what you want:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById("cy"),
    autounselectify: true,
    boxSelectionEnabled: false,

    layout: {
      name: "cola",
      infinite: true
    },

    style: [{
        selector: "node",
        css: {
          "background-color": "#f92411"
        }
      },
      {
        selector: "edge",
        css: {
          "line-color": "#f92411"
        }
      }
    ],
    elements: {
      nodes: [{
          data: {
            id: "1",
            label: "P"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "2",
            label: "sucrose phosphate phosphatase"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "4",
            label: "sucrose 6-phosphate"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "6",
            label: "sucrose"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "8",
            label: "invertase"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "10",
            label: "fructose"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "12",
            label: "fructokinase"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "14",
            label: "fructose 6-phosphate"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "20",
            label: "phosphoglucose isomerase"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "22",
            label: "glucose 6-phosphate"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "28",
            label: "glucose"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "30",
            label: "hexokinase"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "33",
            label: "sucrose synthase"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "36",
            label: "UDP - glucose"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "38",
            label: "sucrose phosphate synthase"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "41",
            label: "UDP"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "44",
            label: "fructose 6-phosphate"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "46",
            label: "ATP"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "47",
            label: "ATP"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "52",
            label: "ATP"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "57",
            label: "ADP"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "66",
            label: "PP"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "71",
            label: "UTP"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "76",
            label: "UDP glucose pyrophosphorylase"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "80",
            label: "glucose 1-phosphate"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "86",
            label: "phospho- glucomutase (cPGM)"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "89",
            label: "G1P transporter"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "90",
            label: "P"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "95",
            label: "P"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "102",
            label: "P"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "103",
            label: "P"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "104",
            label: "G6P transporter"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "109",
            label: "glucose 6-phosphate"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "115",
            label: "phospho- glucomutase (cPGM)"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "121",
            label: "glucose 1-phosphate"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "128",
            label: "ADPglucose pyrophosphorylase (pAGPase)"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "130",
            label: "ADP - glucose"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "136",
            label: "PP"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "141",
            label: "ATP"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "148",
            label: "inorganic diphosphatase"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "149",
            label: "P"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "156",
            label: "phosphate transporter"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "158",
            label: "P"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "164",
            label: "starch synthase (simpl.)"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "166",
            label: "ADP"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "172",
            label: "starch"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "178",
            label: "ATP/ADP transporter"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "179",
            label: "ADP"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "184",
            label: "ADP"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "189",
            label: "ATP"
          }
        }
      ],
      edges: [{
          data: {
            source: "2",
            target: "1"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "4",
            target: "2"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "2",
            target: "6"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "6",
            target: "8"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "8",
            target: "10"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "12",
            target: "14"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "14",
            target: "20"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "20",
            target: "22"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "8",
            target: "28"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "28",
            target: "30"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "30",
            target: "22"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "6",
            target: "33"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "33",
            target: "10"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "33",
            target: "36"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "36",
            target: "38"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "38",
            target: "4"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "38",
            target: "41"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "41",
            target: "33"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "44",
            target: "38"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "52",
            target: "12"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "12",
            target: "57"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "46",
            target: "30"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "30",
            target: "47"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "71",
            target: "76"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "76",
            target: "66"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "76",
            target: "36"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "80",
            target: "76"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "22",
            target: "86"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "86",
            target: "80"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "95",
            target: "89"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "89",
            target: "90"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "102",
            target: "104"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "80",
            target: "89"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "104",
            target: "109"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "115",
            target: "109"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "121",
            target: "89"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "121",
            target: "115"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "121",
            target: "128"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "128",
            target: "130"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "141",
            target: "128"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "128",
            target: "136"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "136",
            target: "148"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "148",
            target: "149"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "149",
            target: "156"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "156",
            target: "158"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "130",
            target: "164"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "164",
            target: "166"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "178",
            target: "179"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "184",
            target: "178"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "178",
            target: "189"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "141",
            target: "178"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "104",
            target: "103"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "10",
            target: "12"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "164",
            target: "172"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "22",
            target: "104"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }));
  cy.unbind('layoutready');
  cy.bind('layoutready', function() {
    cy.fit();
    cy.center();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#cy {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

h1 {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
  <title>cytoscape-cola.js</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  </script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/webcola/WebCola/cola.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape-cola@2.3.0/cytoscape-cola.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>cytoscape-cola</h1>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks good! I use HTML labels in nodes (extension https://github.com/kaluginserg/cytoscape-node-html-label) and I tried to include that in your example, but unfortunately the HTML labels don't stick to the nodes when they move. When I drag a node manually, the label jumps back on the node and then stays at its position while the node moves away.

Also: I'd love to be able to pan and zoom the graph normally, is this possible?

Comment: Due to the continuous layout running, the pan/zoom input are overridden by the draw event, so I don't think this would be possible. I never really used the nodeHTMLlabels, so I am not familiar with that extension. I guess the render doesn't include the labels, so you would need to manually update the positions? Or recall the label command on layoutready? This might not work, but maybe someone else knows more about this.

Comment: The `infinite: true` option does not seem to be mentioned on the github page anymore, so thanks for noting what it was supposed to be used for.